# Moving map while using draw/modify/translate interactions

Tags: openlayers, interaction

I'm using draw/modify/translate interactions to allow users to draw features. But when the user drags a point outside the map, I want the map to move along.

At the moment I'm using version 6.15, but can't find any build-in way to allow this. Is it possible?

Comment: how would a user drag a point outside the map view?

Comment: Maybe poor choice of words. The user cliks and drags a point, and moves the mouse outside the map control.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
const dragInteraction = new Translate();

dragInteraction.on('translating', (event) => {
    const features = event.features.getArray();

    const featureExtents = features.map(x => x.getGeometry()?.getExtent());

    let boundingFeatureExtent = createEmpty();

    for (const extent of featureExtents) {
        if (!extent) {
            continue;
        }
        extend(boundingFeatureExtent, extent)
    }

    const mapView = map.getView();
    const viewExtent = mapView.calculateExtent();

    if (!containsExtent(viewExtent, boundingFeatureExtent)) {
        mapView.fit(extend(viewExtent, boundingFeatureExtent));
    }

})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/komarara/zheuncb3/29/